# There is a strange white line, that is using my Nav's background color, but I don't know why it's there HTML

Tags: html, css

Many problem I have with this website. The other one rarely has any issues.
First of all, I'm undergoing a major re-write of my files to look "neater" and whilst doing so, I managed to make a white line appear under my img with the logo in it. [image]

I'm really unsure what I've done wrong to make it appear, but I actually need it by the end of the book, but on the bottom. But that's not what I'm asking, I'm asking more of what can I do to remove the white space?

My code for the page shown and the CSS is as follows:
**Index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> JavaJam Coffee House</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel= "stylesheet" href="javajam.css">
<!--[if lt IE9]>
<script src="http:html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<header>  
    <h1><img src="javalogo.gif" alt="JavaJam Coffee House Logo" height="117" width="619"></h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id = "content">

<p>
<img class="floatright" src="windingroad.jpg" height="156" width="333">
<ul>
<li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
<li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
<li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
<li>Open Mic Night </li>
</ul>
</p>        

<p> 12312 Main Street <br>
 Mountain Home, CA 93923 <br>
 1-888-555-5555
</div>



    <footer>
    <em>Copyright &copy 2014 JavaJam Coffee House</em> <br>
    <a href="mailto:Johnathon@Olivas.com">Johnathon@Olivas.com</a>
    </footer>
    </body>

    </div>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
header { background-color: #ccaa66;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center; }

h1 { line-height: 200%; }

body { background-color: #ffffcc; 
        color: #330000;
        font-family: Verdana;
        background: url(background.gif) ;
        padding: 25px;}       

nav { text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 10px}
nav a{ text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;}

nav a:link {color: #996633}
nav a:visited {color: #ccaa66}
nav a:hover {color: #330000}
nav ul {list-style-type:none;}

footer { background-color: #ccaa66;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 0.60em;
        font-style: italic;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px; }

#wrapper { 
        background-color: #ffffcc;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 80%; 
        min-width: 700px;
        max-width: 1024px;}

h2 { text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #663300;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    clear: left;}

img { border: 0px solid; }

.details { padding-left: 20%;
           padding-right: 20%; }

#content { padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px; 
    margin-left: 150px;
    background-color: #f2eab7;
    color: #000000; }

.floatleft {float:left;
            padding-right:20px;
            padding-bottom:20px;}

.floatright {float:right;
            padding-left:20px;}

header, nav, main, footer { display: block;}
```

I have checked the index on an online html validator, used it's "edit" and it really messed the page up because it wanted to remove all kinds of things, so I didn't use that one.

If anyone knows what the problem with said white spot is, I would be much appreciative. Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**: Problem has been fixed. I didn't follow the instructions to point, and missed 2 steps (They seemed like it was just telling me things were going to change in the next few steps, so I didn't interpret them as actual steps.)

**Temporary solution: remove `<h1>` and `</h1>` from the header, and the white space goes away.**

Comment: You can set `line-height: 0` on `header`, it's a line break from putting an image in there. Normally you can redefine it for the children. In this case I'm not sure what the function of `h1` is.

Comment: By redefine, does that mean save and reload the page? If not, I'm not entirely sure what you mean.If it does, it didn't change anything. Also, you said line-height, which made me think, what would happen if I removed the <h1> from the header, and bam. That make the white line go away >.>

Comment: Good you got it solved. Not sure what the exact cause was in this case but it was definitely an empty line from having an image inside a block level element. Usually zero line height on the parent works there but it would have to be set again (redefined) for any children that contain text because they would inherit it.